# Nonogram game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, game

I am writing a [Nonogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram) game in JavaScript.

I would like to know your opinions on the code and suggestions on how to improve it.

I'm using a MVC approach.

- the Model has two matrices (represented as linear arrays): one with the actual Nonogram cells and the other with the guesses of the player;
- cells are just strings: Nonogram cells can be either "filled" or "empty"; player guesses can be either "unknown", "filled" or "empty"
- by *sequence* I mean a sequence of consecutive filled cells
- by *definition* I mean the series of *sequences* a row/column has

Here is the source code (I am going to release it under the GNU GPL license):

**utils.js**

```
if (!window.koala) {
    window.koala = {};
}

koala.utils = {
    randomIntegerInRange: function (min, max) {
        return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
    }
};

koala.utils.Event = function (sender) {
    this._sender = sender;
    this._listeners = [];
};

koala.utils.Event.prototype = {
    attach: function (listener) {
        this._listeners.push(listener);
    },

    notify: function (args) {
        for (var index = 0, nlisteners = this._listeners.length; index < nlisteners; index++) {
            this._listeners[index](this._sender, args);
        }
    }
};
```

**nonograms.js**

```
if (!window.koala) {
    window.koala = {};
}

koala.nonograms = {};


/*

    The game uses the MVC pattern.

*/


/*
  __  __           _      _ 
 |  \/  |         | |    | |
 | \  / | ___   __| | ___| |
 | |\/| |/ _ \ / _` |/ _ \ |
 | |  | | (_) | (_| |  __/ |
 |_|  |_|\___/ \__,_|\___|_|

*/

koala.nonograms.Model = function (opts) {
    if (!opts) opts = {};
    this._opts  = opts;

    this.width  = opts.width  = (opts.width  ? Number(opts.width) : 10);
    this.height = opts.height = (opts.height ? Number(opts.height) : 10);

    // Events fired by the model
    this.events = {};

    // The ussr guessed the content of a cell
    this.events.guessChanged     = new koala.utils.Event(this);

    // The nonogram has been changed
    this.events.nonogramChanged  = new koala.utils.Event(this);

    // The user solved the nonogram
    this.events.nonogramSolved   = new koala.utils.Event(this);

    // The nonogram was solved but now it isn't
    this.events.nonogramUnsolved = new koala.utils.Event(this);
};


koala.nonograms.Model.prototype = {
    getCellAt: function (x, y) {
        var index = this._indexFromXY(x, y);
        var cell = this._actual[index];

        return (cell === undefined) ? "empty" : cell;
    },

    getGuessAt: function (x, y) {
        var index = this._indexFromXY(x, y);
        var guess = this._guess[index];

        return (guess === undefined) ? "unknown" : guess;
    },

    setGuessAt: function (x, y, guess) {
        var oldGuess = this.getGuessAt(x, y);
        var index = this._indexFromXY(x, y);
        this._guess[index] = guess;

        this.events.guessChanged.notify({
                   x: x,
                   y: y,
            oldGuess: oldGuess,
            newGuess: guess
        });

        var was_solved = this.isSolved();
        this._checkIfSolved();
        var is_solved = this.isSolved();

        if (was_solved && !is_solved) {
            this.events.nonogramUnsolved.notify();
        } else if (!was_solved && is_solved) {
            this.events.nonogramSolved.notify();
        }
    },

    isSolved: function () {
        return this._solved;
    },

    getRowDefinition: function (row) {
        var definition = [];

        var sequenceBegin;
        var sequenceEnd;
        var sequenceSolved;
        var sequenceLength = 0;

        for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
            if (this.getCellAt(x, row) === "filled") {
                if (sequenceLength === 0) sequenceBegin = x;
                sequenceLength++;
            } else if (sequenceLength) {
                sequenceEnd = x-1;

                sequenceSolved = false;
                if ((sequenceBegin === 0 || this.getGuessAt(sequenceBegin-1, row) === "empty")
                    && (sequenceEnd === this.width-1 || this.getGuessAt(sequenceEnd+1, row) === "empty")) {

                    sequenceSolved = true;
                    for (var index = sequenceBegin; index <= sequenceEnd; index++) {
                        if (this.getGuessAt(index, row) != "filled") {
                            sequenceSolved = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                definition.push({
                    length: sequenceLength,
                    solved: sequenceSolved
                });

                sequenceLength = 0;
            }
        }

        if (sequenceLength) {
            sequenceEnd = x-1;

            sequenceSolved = false;
            if ((sequenceBegin === 0 || this.getGuessAt(sequenceBegin-1, row) === "empty")
                && (sequenceEnd === this.width-1 || this.getGuessAt(sequence_end+1, row) === "empty")) {

                sequenceSolved = true;
                for (var index = sequenceBegin; index <= sequenceEnd; index++) {
                    if (this.getGuessAt(index, row) != "filled") {
                        sequenceSolved = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            definition.push({
                length: sequenceLength,
                solved: sequenceSolved
            });
        }
        return definition;
    },

    getColumnDefinition: function (col) {
        var definition = [];

        var sequenceBegin;
        var sequenceEnd;
        var sequenceSolved;
        var sequenceLength = 0;

        for (var y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
            if (this.getCellAt(col, y) === "filled") {
                if (sequenceLength === 0) sequenceBegin = y;
                sequenceLength++;
            } else if (sequenceLength) {
                sequenceEnd = y-1;

                sequenceSolved = false;
                if ((sequenceBegin === 0 || this.getGuessAt(col, sequenceBegin-1) === "empty")
                    && (sequenceEnd === this.height-1 || this.getGuessAt(col, sequenceEnd+1) === "empty")) {

                    sequenceSolved = true;
                    for (var index = sequenceBegin; index <= sequenceEnd; index++) {
                        if (this.getGuessAt(col, index) != "filled") {
                            sequenceSolved = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                definition.push({
                    length: sequenceLength,
                    solved: sequenceSolved
                });

                sequenceLength = 0;
            }
        }

        if (sequenceLength) {
            sequenceEnd = y-1;

            sequenceSolved = false;
            if ((sequenceBegin === 0 || this.getGuessAt(col, sequenceBegin-1) === "empty")
                && (sequenceEnd === this.height-1 || this.getGuessAt(col, sequenceEnd+1) === "empty")) {

                sequenceSolved = true;
                for (var index = sequenceBegin; index <= sequenceEnd; index++) {
                    if (this.getGuessAt(col, index) != "filled") {
                        sequenceSolved = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            definition.push({
                length: sequenceLength,
                solved: sequenceSolved
            });
        }

        return definition;
    },

    randomize: function (density) {
        this._setupNonogram();

        var ncells = this.width * this.height;
        var to_be_filled = Math.floor(ncells * density);
        if (to_be_filled > ncells) to_be_filled = ncells;

        var index;
        while (to_be_filled) {
            index = this._getRandomIndex();
            if (this._actual[index] === undefined) {
                this._actual[index] = "filled";
                to_be_filled--;
            }
        }

        this.events.nonogramChanged.notify();
    },

    // Private methods
    _setupNonogram: function () {
        var ncells = this.width * this.height;

        this._actual = new Array(ncells);
        this._guess  = new Array(ncells);
        this._solved = false;
    },

    _indexFromXY: function (x, y) {
        return y * this.width + x;
    },

    _getRandomIndex: function () {
        var ncells = this.width * this.height;
        return koala.utils.randomIntegerInRange(0, ncells - 1);
    },

    _checkIfSolved: function () {
        for (var index = 0, ncells = this._actual.length; index < ncells; index++) {
            if ((this._actual[index] === "filled" && this._guess[index] != "filled") ||
                (this._actual[index] != "filled" && this._guess[index] == "filled")) {
                this._solved = false;
                return;
             }
        }
        this._solved = true;
    },
};






/*
 __      ___               
 \ \    / (_)              
  \ \  / / _  _____      __
   \ \/ / | |/ _ \ \ /\ / /
    \  /  | |  __/\ V  V / 
     \/   |_|\___| \_/\_/  

 */

koala.nonograms.View = function (model, container) {
    this._model = model;
    this._container = $(container);
    this._id = "nonogram" + koala.utils.randomIntegerInRange(0, 1000000);
    this._theme = "default";

    // Events fired by the View
    this.events = {};

    this.events.clickOnCell     = new koala.utils.Event(this);
    this.events.mouseDownOnCell = new koala.utils.Event(this);
    this.events.mouseUp         = new koala.utils.Event(this);
    this.events.mouseEntersCell = new koala.utils.Event(this);
    this.events.mouseLeavesCell = new koala.utils.Event(this);
}

koala.nonograms.View.prototype = {
    show: function () {
        this.rebuildNonogram();
    },

    setSolved: function () {
        $("#" + this._id).removeClass("nonogram_playing").addClass("nonogram_solved");
    },

    setUnsolved: function () {
        $("#" + this._id).removeClass("nonogram_solved").addClass("nonogram_playing");
    },

    setTheme: function (theme) {
        $("#" + this._id).removeClass(this._theme).addClass(theme);
        this._theme = theme;
    },

    highlightColumn: function (col) {
        this._container.find(".nonogram_column_" + col + "_cell").addClass("nonogram_hovered_column");
        this._container.find("#" + this._idOfColumnDefinition(col)).addClass("nonogram_hovered_column");
    },

    unhighlightColumn: function (col) {
        this._container.find(".nonogram_column_" + col + "_cell").removeClass("nonogram_hovered_column");
        this._container.find("#" + this._idOfColumnDefinition(col)).removeClass("nonogram_hovered_column");
    },

    setGuessAt: function (x, y, newGuess) {
        var cell = $("#" + this._idOfCell(x, y));
        var oldGuess = cell.data().guess;

        cell
        .removeClass("nonogram_correct_guess")
        .removeClass(this._guessToCSSClass(oldGuess))
        .addClass(this._guessToCSSClass(newGuess))
        .data({guess: newGuess});

        if (this._model.getCellAt(x, y) === newGuess) {
            cell.addClass("nonogram_correct_guess");
        }

        // Update row & column definitions
        $("#" + this._idOfRowDefinition(y)).html(this._rowDefinitionToHTML(this._model.getRowDefinition(y)));
        $("#" + this._idOfColumnDefinition(x)).html(this._columnDefinitionToHTML(this._model.getColumnDefinition(x)));
    },

    rebuildNonogram: function () {
        var width  = this._model.width,
            height = this._model.height;

        var x, y, tr;

        var table = $("<table/>").attr("id", this._id).addClass("nonogram").addClass(this._theme);
        if (this._model.isSolved())
            table.addClass("nonogram_solved");
        else
            table.addClass("nonogram_playing");

        // Column Definitions Row
        tr = $("<tr/>").addClass("nonogram_row");

        // Top Left cell
        $("<td>").addClass("nonogram_top_left_cell").appendTo(tr);

        for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            if (x && x % 5 === 0) {
                $("<td/>").addClass("nonogram_separation_column").appendTo(tr);
            }

            $("<td/>")
            .attr("id", this._idOfColumnDefinition(x))
            .addClass("nonogram_definition nonogram_column_definition")
            .html(this._columnDefinitionToHTML(this._model.getColumnDefinition(x)))
            .appendTo(tr);
        }
        tr.appendTo(table);

        for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            // Separate groups of five rows
            if (y && y % 5 == 0) {
                $("<tr/>")
                .addClass("nonogram_separation_row")
                .append($("<td colspan='" + (width + width - 1) + "'/>"))
                .appendTo(table);
            }

            // Create new row
            tr = $("<tr/>").addClass("nonogram_row");

            // Create definition for the current row
            $("<td/>")
            .attr("id", this._idOfRowDefinition(y))
            .addClass("nonogram_definition nonogram_row_definition")
            .html(this._rowDefinitionToHTML(this._model.getRowDefinition(y)))
            .appendTo(tr);

            for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                // Separate groups of five columns
                if (x && x % 5 === 0) {
                    $("<td/>")
                    .addClass("nonogram_separation_column")
                    .appendTo(tr);
                }

                // Build the actual nonogram cell
                $("<td/>")
                .attr("id", this._idOfCell(x, y))
                .addClass(this._CSSClassesForCell(x, y))
                .data({
                        x: x,
                        y: y,
                    guess: this._model.getGuessAt(x, y)
                })
                .appendTo(tr);
            }
            tr.appendTo(table);
        }

        this._container
        .hide()
        .empty()
        .append(table)
        .fadeIn(500);

        // Events firing code
        var view = this;
        table.click(function (e) {
            if (e.target.nodeName != "TD") return;

            e.preventDefault();
            var cellData = $(e.target).data();
            view.events.clickOnCell.notify(cellData);
        });

        table.mousedown(function (e) {
            if (e.target.nodeName != "TD") return;

            e.preventDefault();
            var cellData = $(e.target).data();
            view.events.mouseDownOnCell.notify(cellData);
        });

        $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            view.events.mouseUp.notify({event: e});
        });

        table.mouseover(function (e) {
            if (e.target.nodeName != "TD") return;

            e.preventDefault();
            var cellData = $(e.target).data();
            view.events.mouseEntersCell.notify(cellData);
        });

        table.mouseout(function (e) {
            if (e.target.nodeName != "TD") return;

            e.preventDefault();
            var cellData = $(e.target).data();
            view.events.mouseLeavesCell.notify(cellData);
        });
    },

    // Private methods
    _idOfCell: function (x, y) {
        return this._id + "_x_" + x + "_y_" + y;
    },

    _idOfRowDefinition: function (row) {
        return this._id + "_row_" + row + "_definition";
    },

    _idOfColumnDefinition: function (col) {
        return this._id + "_column_" + col + "_definition";
    },

    _rowDefinitionToHTML: function (sequences) {
        var html = "<nobr>";
        for (var index = 0; index < sequences.length; index++) {
            if (index) html += "&nbsp;";
            html += "<span class='nonogram_sequence";
            if (sequences[index].solved) {
                html += " nonogram_solved_sequence";
            }
            html += "'>" + sequences[index].length + "</span>";
        }
        html += "</nobr>";
        return html;
    },

    _columnDefinitionToHTML: function (sequences) {
        var html = "";
        for (var index = 0; index < sequences.length; index++) {
            if (index) html += "<br>";
            html += "<nobr><span class='nonogram_sequence";
            if (sequences[index].solved) {
                html += " nonogram_solved_sequence";
            }
            html += "'>" + sequences[index].length + "</span></nobr>";
        }
        return html;
    },

    _CSSClassesForCell: function (x, y) {
        var cellGuess  = this._model.getGuessAt(x, y);
        var actualCell = this._model.getCellAt(x, y);

        var classes = [];

        classes.push("nonogram_cell");
        classes.push("nonogram_column_" + x + "_cell");
        classes.push(this._guessToCSSClass(cellGuess));

        if (cellGuess === actualCell) {
            classes.push("nonogram_correct_guess");
        }

        return classes.join(" ");
    },

    _guessToCSSClass: function (guess) {
        return "nonogram_" + guess + "_cell";
    }
};


/*
   _____            _             _ _           
  / ____|          | |           | | |          
 | |     ___  _ __ | |_ _ __ ___ | | | ___ _ __ 
 | |    / _ \| '_ \| __| '__/ _ \| | |/ _ \ '__|
 | |___| (_) | | | | |_| | | (_) | | |  __/ |   
  \_____\___/|_| |_|\__|_|  \___/|_|_|\___|_|   

*/

koala.nonograms.Controller = function (model, view) {
    this._dragHelper = new koala.nonograms.dragHelper();

    this._model = model;
    this._view = view;
    var controller = this;

    // Application Logic
    model.events.nonogramChanged.attach(function () {
        view.rebuildNonogram();
    });

    model.events.guessChanged.attach(function (model, opts) {
        view.setGuessAt(opts.x, opts.y, opts.newGuess);
    });

    model.events.nonogramSolved.attach(function () {
        view.setSolved();
    });

    model.events.nonogramUnsolved.attach(function () {
        view.setUnsolved();
    });

    view.events.mouseDownOnCell.attach(function (view, cell) {
        controller._dragHelper.start(cell.x, cell.y, controller._nextGuess(model.getGuessAt(cell.x, cell.y)));
        controller._previewDragging();
    });

    view.events.mouseUp.attach(function () {
        if (!controller._dragHelper.isDragging())
            return;
        controller._dragHelper.stop();
        controller._cancelDraggingPreview();
        controller._applyDragging();
    });

    view.events.mouseEntersCell.attach(function (view, cell) {
        view.highlightColumn(cell.x);
        if (!controller._dragHelper.isDragging()) return;

        controller._cancelDraggingPreview();
        controller._dragHelper.to(cell.x, cell.y);
        controller._previewDragging();
    });

    view.events.mouseLeavesCell.attach(function (view, cell) {
        view.unhighlightColumn(cell.x);
    });
}

koala.nonograms.Controller.prototype = {
    // Private methods

    // cycles in [unknown, filled, empty]
    _nextGuess: function (guess) {
        if (guess === "unknown") {
            return "filled";
        } else if (guess === "filled") {
            return "empty";
        }
        return "unknown";
    },

    _previewDragging: function () {
        var view = this._view;

        this._dragHelper.iterateOverDraggedCells(function (x, y, guess) {
            view.setGuessAt(x, y, guess);
        });
    },

    _applyDragging: function () {
        var model = this._model;

        this._dragHelper.iterateOverDraggedCells(function (x, y, guess) {
            model.setGuessAt(x, y, guess);
        });
    },

    _cancelDraggingPreview: function () {
        var model = this._model;
        var view  = this._view;

        this._dragHelper.iterateOverDraggedCells(function (x, y, guess) {
            view.setGuessAt(x, y, model.getGuessAt(x, y));
        });
    }
};

/*****************************************************/

koala.nonograms.dragHelper = function () {
    this._dragging = false;
};

koala.nonograms.dragHelper.prototype = {
    start: function (x, y, guess) {
        this._x1 = this._x2 = x;
        this._y1 = this._y2 = y;
        this._guess = guess;

        this._dragging = true;
    },

    to: function (x, y) {
        this._x2 = x;
        this._y2 = y;
    },

    stop: function () {
        this._dragging = false;
    },

    isDragging: function () {
        return this._dragging;
    },

    iterateOverDraggedCells: function (fn) {
        var x1 = this._x1;
        var y1 = this._y1;
        var x2 = this._x2;
        var y2 = this._y2;

        var fromX, toX, stepX, fromY, toY, stepY;

        if (Math.abs(x1-x2) > Math.abs(y1-y2)) {
            // Horizontal Line
            stepX = 1;
            stepY = 0;

            fromY = toY = y1;

            if (x1 < x2) {
                fromX = x1;
                toX = x2;
            } else {
                fromX = x2;
                toX = x1;
            }
        } else {
            // Vertical line
            stepX = 0;
            stepY = 1;

            fromX = toX = x1;

            if (y1 < y2) {
                fromY = y1;
                toY = y2;
            } else {
                fromY = y2;
                toY = y1;
            }
        }

        for (var x = fromX, y = fromY; x <= toX && y <= toY; x += stepX, y += stepY) {
            fn(x, y, this._guess);
        }
    }
};

/*****************************************************/
/*  The main Nonogram object                         */
/*****************************************************/

koala.nonograms.Nonogram = function (container, opts) {
    this._container = container;
    opts = opts || {};

    this._opts = {
         width: opts.width  || 10,
        height: opts.height || 10,
         theme: opts.theme  || "default"
    };

    this._model = new koala.nonograms.Model({
         width: this._opts.width,
        height: this._opts.height
    });
    this._view = new koala.nonograms.View(this._model, this._container);
    this._view.setTheme(this._opts.theme);
    this._controller = new koala.nonograms.Controller(this._model, this._view);
}

koala.nonograms.Nonogram.prototype = {
    show: function () {
        this._view.show();
    },

    randomize: function (opts) {
        var density = 0.60;
        if (opts && opts.density) {
            density = opts.density;
        }

        this._model.randomize(density);
    },

    setTheme: function (theme) {
            this._opts.theme = theme;
            this._view.setTheme(theme);
    }
};
```

If you want to try it in action I uploaded it [here](http://freenonograms.altervista.org).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, it looks good to me.

My 2 cents:

- I am not sure why you have event related things in your model
- `iterateOverDraggedCells` looked like it could use some refactoring.

  - Whenever you start with x1,y1,x2,y2, I think it is better to have a point object with x and y.
  - You can use Math.min() and Math.max() to find which value is the lowest/highest
  - It looks like you went too far with DRY in that last for() loop

> ```
>  iterateOverDraggedCells: function ( fn )
>  {
>    var p1 = {  x : this._x1 , y : this._y1 },
>        p2 = {  x : this._x2 , y : this._y2 },
>        from, to;
>
>    if( Math.abs( p1.x - p2.x ) > Math.abs( p1.y - p2.y ) ) 
>    {
>      from = { x : Math.min( p1.x ,p2.x ) , y :  p1.y  };
>      to   = { x : Math.max( p1.x ,p2.x ) };
>      for( var x = from.x, y = from.y ; x <= to.x , x++ )
>        fn(x, y, this._guess);   
>    }
>    else
>    {
>      from  = { y : Math.min( p1.y , p2.y ) , x :  p1.x  };
>      to    = { y : Math.max( p1.y , p2.y ) };
>      for( var x = from.x, y = from.y ; y <= to.y , y++ )
>        fn(x, y, this._guess);
>    }
>
>  }
> ```

Taking that into account, you could try something like the above.